# problems entering data into mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf

i have this code that is being used to enter data into mysql, but I have found an error that says:

"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11/05/2018)' at line 1'"

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string especie = txt1.Text;
        string nombre = txt2.Text;
        string fechanac = txt3.Text;
        string fecharev = txt4.Text;
        int numanimales = 0;
        int cont = 0;

        var dbCon = DBConnection.Instance();
        dbCon.DatabaseName = "animalia";

        if (dbCon.IsConnect())
        {
            string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANIMALES;";
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbCon.Connection);
            numanimales = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }

        int id = numanimales + 1;

        if (dbCon.IsConnect())
        {
            if (especie == "" || nombre == "" || fechanac == "" || fecharev == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Introduzca todos los datos");
            }
            else
            {
                cont = 1;

                MySqlDataReader reader;

                string query = "INSERT INTO ANIMALES VALUES (" + id + ",FALSE,'" + especie + "','" + nombre + "','" + fechanac + "','" + fecharev + "');";

                var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbCon.Connection);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                MessageBox.Show("Animal añadido");
                reader.Close();
            }

            if (cont == 1)
            {
                this.Close();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

The error appears in this part of the code

```
MySqlDataReader reader;

            string query = "INSERT INTO ANIMALES VALUES (" + id + ",FALSE,'" + especie + "','" + nombre + "','" + fechanac + "','" + fecharev + ");";

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbCon.Connection);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            MessageBox.Show("Animal añadido");
            reader.Close();
```

Thank you very much in advance to those of you who can help me.

Comment: Show a messagebox after the query to check it

Comment: Don't do this. Use parameters instead of building a sql command string up using string objexts. https://www.google.com/url?q=https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html ... Sure there's better links but it shows the basic approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing quotation marks on the last attribute:

```
...,'" + fecharev + ");";
```

should be

```
...,'" + fecharev + "');";
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.... can you write the whole line? My final parentheses are brown as if there's something not rightly closed.

Comment: With the missing tick, it looks correct now. Can you post the generated SQL statement?